# The com.wangsun.upi library reports: "No UPI app found, please install one to continue"

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, upi

With:

```
implementation 'com.wangsun.upi.payment:upi-payment:0.0.5'
```

This library only gives me an error: "`No UPI app found, please install one to continue`" in Samsung mobiles.

```
       PaymentDetail payment = new PaymentDetail(payeeVpa,payeeName,
            "","", description,String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(amount)));
    new UpiPayment(this)
            .setPaymentDetail(payment)
            .setUpiApps(newList)
            .setCallBackListener(new UpiPayment.OnUpiPaymentListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull TransactionDetails transactionDetails) {
                    Log.e("success", String.valueOf(transactionDetails));
                    Toast.makeText(AddPointsActivity.this, "transaction sucess: " + transactionDetails, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(transactionDetails.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
                    {
                        String user_id= session_management.getUserDetails().get(KEY_ID);
                         }
                    else
                    {
                        common.showToast("Payment Failed.");
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onSubmitted(@NonNull TransactionDetails transactionDetails) {
                    Log.e("onSubmitted", String.valueOf(transactionDetails));
                    Toast.makeText(AddPointsActivity.this, "transaction pending: " + transactionDetails, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onError( String message) {
                    Log.e("error", String.valueOf(message));
                    Toast.makeText(AddPointsActivity.this, "transaction failed: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).pay();
```

Answer (score -1):

Above android targetsdkVersion 30

Need to add AndroidManifest.xml below

< queries > < package android:name='com.csam.icic.bank.imobile' /> < package android:name='in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping' /> < package android:name='in.org.npci.upiapp' /> < package android:name='com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user' /> < package android:name='com.phonepe.app' /> < package android:name='code here`ame="net.one97.paytm' /> < package android:name='com.mobikwik_new' />

Comment: but now I am facing another issue.
I am using a BharatPe merchant id for payment but it is not working.
getting errors like the bank not accepting the payment or due to some safety reason payment can not be initiated